# How can I get all phone numbers from addressbook IOS 5 KABPersonPhoneProperty

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.3

I am using kABPersonPhoneProperty to get the iPhone "phone numbers" from the address book. However, once I run the program and only one phone number appears even the contact person has mobile, home and iphone numbers. Please help and I hope can get all phone numbers from every contact. Thanks.

The full method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }
    // cell.textLabel.text = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    ABRecordRef record = (__bridge   ABRecordRef) [people objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

    NSString *lastName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

    NSLog(@"FirstName %@, LastName %@", firstName, lastName);

    cell.nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

    ABMultiValueRef mainPhone = ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(mainPhone); i ++) {        

        NSString *phoneMobileNumber = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(mainPhone, i);

        cell.telNo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@" , home, phoneMobileNumber];

        NSLog(@"%@,%@", home, phoneMobileNumber);
    }

return cell;

}
```

Comment: Where is the text supposed to appear? In a tableview cell?

Comment: Yes in a tableview cell and the tableview cell has the Name and contact number fields for contact name and contact number. How can the contact number result(s) (all kind of contact number including Main, Mobile and Iphone) can be shown in the contact number field?

Comment: So is this in a `<UITableViewDataSource>` method?

Comment: I am implementing in (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath from <UITableViewDataSource> protocol.

Comment: Could you post the entire `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?

Comment: Hi... I edit the question content and include the whole cellForRowAtIndexPath: method... Thanks

Comment: A couple things. One, where is the `people` array declared? Two, where are the `nameLabel` and `telNo` properties of `cell` coming from? Sorry for asking a lot of questions... :)

Comment: the people array declared in viewDidLoad and I create 2 variables nameLabel is for first and last name and telNo for all phone numbers

Answer (score 1):

ok here is **solution**

```
`    ABAddressBookRef addressBook=ABAddressBookCreate();
NSArray *allPeople=(NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);


NSMutableArray *holdEachPersonMobileNumbers=[NSMutableArray new];

for (id person in allPeople) {
    ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = ABRecordCopyValue(( ABRecordRef)(person), kABPersonPhoneProperty);

    NSString* mobile=@"";
    for (int i=0; i < ABMultiValueGetCount(phoneNumbers); i++) {

        mobile = (NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, i);

        NSCharacterSet *trim = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"#();$&-+"];
        mobile = [[mobile componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: trim] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
        mobile= [mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

        mobile=[mobile stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        [holdEachPersonMobileNumbers addObject:mobile];
    }

}
```

`

Here **holdEachPersonMobileNumbers** hold all numbers associated to particular person which u select in address book

**put above code in this method**
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person

Hope u **conform** this protocol  **ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate**
and **import** this

```
    #import <AddressBook/AddressBook.h>
#import <AddressBookUI/AddressBookUI.h>
```